# How to render html which is within script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have some html content which is within the  tag i want to render this html when i run the code in browser. the code is following.

```
<script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="clearfix">
    <div class="container"> <a id="logo" href="index.html">Login</a>
      <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="#" class="icon flip">Sign Up |</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="icon">Forget Password</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <article class="clearfix" >
      <aside role="complementary" class="shadow">
          <div id="error"></div>
          <form class="c-form" name="login" id="login">
          <input type="text" id="user-name" name="email" value="User Name">
          <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="Password">

          <input type="submit" class="button green" value="Sign Up">
        </form>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </section>

</div>
</script>
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to render this ? Is it through some script? or simply show this somewhere in your html ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @ryadavilli by any way. please suggest your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give the script tag an id, select that tag and append its html content.
See here http://jsfiddle.net/rohhittt/zwMNr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').append($("#scriptId").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign complete HTML as a string to Javascript variable and put that variable where u want to place this snippt

var htmlcode = *your template HTML code*

$("#testDiv").html(htmlcode)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but anyways the idea is same as my predecessor said. Add ID parameter to the script tag and set type to text/html than just "inject" content from script to DOM like so (help yourself with jQuery):

```
<span>Some text</span>  
<div id="injectionArea">
</div>

<script id="scriptContainer" type="text/html">
  <div>SOME CONTENT INSIDE SCRIPT</div>
</script>

$('#injectionArea').html($('#scriptContainer').html());
```

Example in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ypcjG/2/

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

1. Add the templated code at the end of your html document
2. Get it with jquery and remove the id-tag
3. insert it wherever you need it

Step 1:

```
<body>
    <div id="templateContainer" style="display:none;">
        <div id="templateForYou"><h1>Test</h1></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Step 2:

```
//step 2
var template = $('#templateForYou').clone().removeAttr('id');
// step3
$('#someWhereElse').append(template);
```