# How to add HTML in between script tag

Tags: javascript, html

For example this is my code

```
<html>
  <head><title>Document</title></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let input0 = parseInt(prompt("Write a number"))
      let input1 = parseInt(prompt("Write an other number"))
      if (input0 === input1){
        //Here I want to print some text on webpage intead of
        //using document.write or console.log
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

now i want to print a text in h1 tag but if the condition mets, how can i perform this task

Comment: Use innerHTML to set the data for your `h1` tag

Comment: look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529327/change-the-value-of-h1-element-within-a-form-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render html which is within script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275031/how-to-render-html-which-is-within-script-tag)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please [read introductory tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) before resorting to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. use createElement("H1") to create a h1 tag
2. use createTextNode("") to create text content and append it to h1 tag
3. append h1 tag to document.body

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let input0 = parseInt(prompt("Write a number"));
      let input1 = parseInt(prompt("Write an other number"));
      if (input0 === input1) {
        //Here I want to print some text on webpage intead of
        //using document.write or console.log
        var h1 = document.createElement("H1");
        var text = document.createTextNode("Hi there!");
        h1.append(text);
        document.body.append(h1);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding elements to the body is ok, but your approach won't add h1 to the exact place. It only adds to the end of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is the wrong approach. You should add a script tag at the end of the body tag. And you have to add a container, where you want to add your H1 tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="h1-container"></div>
    <script>
      let input0 = parseInt(prompt("Write a number"));
      let input1 = parseInt(prompt("Write an other number"));
      if (input0 === input1) {
        //Here I want to print some text on webpage intead of
        //using document.write or console.log
        const container = document.querySelector(".h1-container");
        const h1 = document.createElement("H1");
        const text = document.createTextNode("Hi there!");
        h1.append(text);
        container.append(h1);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```